# Table select / deselect cells on click and mouseover without ui

Tags: jquery, select, cell, mouseover

What I'm trying to do is a few things. but I created a fiddle to demonstrate whats happening -> http://jsfiddle.net/yohn/tDcgD/ and just so people know, some code came from https://github.com/stevedev/jquery.table_select.js.

You can click on a cell within the table and drag, it should highlight the cells and keep them in the respective grid  view, but whenever I go back while within the same mousedown event I want it to unselect the recently selected cells, and I've been having the hardest time trying to get that right.. Looking for how it works within word in a way when you're creating a new table.

I know the fix would be dealing within the following loop, but I can't get it right..

```
for (y = start_y; y <= end_y; y++){
    for (x = start_x; x <= end_x; x++){
        table.find('tr:eq('+y+')').find('td:eq('+x+')').each(function (i,o) {
            var th = $(this)
            if(th.hasClass('selectable')){
                if(th.hasClass('recent')){} else {
                    th.toggleClass("selected").addClass('recent')
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, this is what you are after. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDcgD/2/)

If you look at `.delegate('td.selectable', 'mouseover', function ()`, I've added the following piece of code.

```
else
{                             
    $('.recent').removeClass('recent').removeClass('selected')
}
```

Basically if mouse is clicked (mousedown) and hovered (that is when 'recent' class is present) initially clear the 'recent' and 'selected' classes from the elements. Rest of the logic will take care of the rendering/ filling of the calculated grid.

This should address your question. However you may need to look into other things according to your needs.

Comment: how did I not see that.. Thanks for taking a look and fixing it!! much appreciated

Comment: is there way to add a weeks drop down to this?

Comment: @bews99 this is out of context from the original question from OP. However this should be doable; I would suggest to post it as a new question with what you have tried.